# changed service account through config manager, SSIS jobs are nopw failing with master key errors

Tags: sql-server

We changed the service account for SQL (2016 failover cluster) over the weekend through configuration manager (to a gMSA)

```
SELECT *
FROM master.sys.symmetric_keys AS SK
WHERE SK.name = '##MS_ServiceMasterKey##'
```

shows the modify date as the weekend, however SSIS jobs are failing with an error

> An error occurred during Service Master Key decryption [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 33094)  Could not use view or function XXX because of binding errors

Can anyone suggest where to go from here please? Should I try to regenerate the key manually?

Comment: Hope this URL has sollution to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637592/an-error-occurred-during-service-master-key-decryption-when-trying-to-create-s

Comment: yes that resolved it :) thank you very much